Not understanding reflection of function across lines
So I am currently studying reflection across lines (mainly the x-axis or the y-axis) of functions, and I don't know how to approach this or understand it.
If we have the function f(x) and were to reflect it horizontally or vertically across lines, how would we write the new reflected function, say g(x), in terms of f(x)? I know for horizontal reflection across x-axis (or y = 0 line) would be -f(x) and vertical reflection across y-axis (x = 0 line) would be f(-x), but why does this occur?
And what happens if we were to reflect the function across lines where x = a, or y = a? (Where a is just a constant Real number)
Please explain this in detail if anyone can spare their time for it, thank you.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Reflecting across the horizontal axis, y becomes -y, whatever y is. In your case $y=f(x)$ so $f(x)$ becomes $-f(x)$. Reflecting across the x axis, x becomes -x so that $f(x)$ becomes $f(-x)$. It is about reflection, not f. If y is some value on the y axis where would it reflect to across the horizontal line at a?

@Paul I understand that horizontal reflection across x-axis means changing f(x) into -f(x). For example, reflecting the function $f(x) = x^3 + 5x^2 - 2x + 3$ across x-axis would be $g(x) = -x^3 - 5x^2 + 2x -3$ and for vertical reflection across y-axis would be changing all x in f(x) into -x, so f(-x). However, what I don't understand is what happens if we reflect horizontally across the line, say, y = 3? And to generalize, what about y = a? Same thing for line x = 3 and x = a, how would we write the new reflected g(x) in terms of f(x) in that case? Is there a certain formula for this?

@Paul and if we can generalize the reflection across lines, then since x-axis and y-axis is simply y = 0 and x = 0, we could just put 0 for x = a and y = a.
My approach to this was to use the formula for distance between a point and a line, since all points on f(x) are the same distance from the axis of reflection as the points on the reflected function g(x). For horizontal reflections, if we have a line y = a, then the distance would be $\left\lvert f(x) - a\right\rvert$= c. With this, we can write two equations:
f(x) - a = c and f(x) - a = -c.

Multiplying 1 to the 2nd equation, we get -f(x) + a = c. This is equivalent to the first equation, so
f(x) - a = -f(x) + a, f(x) = -f(x) + 2a.
So basically, the new translated g(x) would be -f(x) + 2a, at least that's what I think. I just want to know if what I did was mathematically correct and if this is a correct way of thinking about horizontal reflections? Same thing for vertical reflections, in this case I know all the x's are equidistant, and using the same logic we get $\lvert x - a\rvert$ = c, x - a = c and x - a = -c, Multiplying by -1, x - a = -x + a, and we get x = -x + 2a.

So the x values that go into the new reflected function g(x) would be -x + 2a, to give an example if we have $f(x) = x^2 + 2x - 1$ and we reflected that vertically across line x = 5, we would replace all x in f(x) with -x + 2(5) which is -x + 10, so we would get f(-x + 10) = g(x) the new reflected function, which would be: $g(x) = (-x+10)^2 + 2(-x+10) + 1$
Now like I mentioned, I just wanted to know if what I did was correct, if it's a good and viable method/way to think about this, if there are any mistakes or things to improve and whether or not there are other ways to look at this.

That all looks good to me. You could simplify by asking what happens to $y-a$ when you reflect across the horizontal at a. This must become $-y+a$ so that in turn $y$ must map to $-y+2a$.
